# Two "distanted" cities?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

The two distanted cities are included in our comparison.

Is it the correct usage for "distanted"? Do we have an adjective serving our goal here? I want an adjective to fill the blank to imply that the cities are far away to each other.

The two ________ cities are included in our comparison.

Comment: "Distanted" is not a word. Do you mean "distant"? I don't think you need any word at that point in the sentence, you can just say "the two cities are far away from each other". (Note it's "away from" not "away to".)

Comment: You may find our sister site *English Language Learners* more helpful for this type of question.

Comment: look, if you fill in the blank with a word that means the cities are far away from each other, then the sentence becomes redundant. second, I agree with nnnnnn that *distanted* is not [being used as a word](https://www.onelook.com/?w=distanted&ls=a) according to a possible plethora of dictionaries. do you mean *distant*? that means far away, but not far away from each other.

Comment: we also say "far away from each other"

Comment: 1) 'distanted' is not a word, you probably are looking for 'distant'. 2) It is redundant to use both 'distant' and 'far way fron each other'. "The two cities are far away from each other." = "The cities are distant." is how you would say it in two different ways. 3) It should be 'far away _from_'. 4) Questions like 'Is this correct?' are probably best asked on https://ELL.stackexchange.cpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called best *single* adjective you could use for this is [**equidistant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equidistant):

> 1 : equally distant
>   // a location equidistant from two major cities

In the example sentence, that would be:

> The two equidistant cities are included in our comparison.

---

However, I said "so-called" because there are two problems with *equidistant*:

1. Normally, two or more things are equidistant from something else.
2. That they are equidistant doesn't necessarily imply that there is a *great* distance between them. You could, for instance, say that the I and M keys on a keyboard are equidistant from the K key, even though they are not far apart from each other at all.

So, while the meaning of *equidistant* might be conveyed in the right context, the adjective entirely on its own doesn't convey that meaning. But it's not clear what the context of the sentence in the question actually is. If the comparison being discussed talks about things with a great amount of space between them, then *the two equidistant cities* could work.

---

If an adjectival *phrase* is acceptable, you could say something like this:

> The two *mutually and greatly distant* cities are included in our comparison.

The adjectives *mutually* ("directed by each toward the other or the others," as per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutually)) and *greatly* combine to express exactly what you want to express, and the sentence doesn't need to be rephrased.

Comment: So the phrase "two distant cities" means that those two cities are far from each other?

Comment: Completely on its own, the phrase *two distant cities* doesn't necessarily mean that they are (greatly) distant from *each other*. That's why I used both *equidistant* and *mutually* in my answer. In *two distant cities*, they could be very close to each other—but *distant* could describe their common location with respect to something else.

Comment: The question did not seem to me to suggest the cities were *equidistant* from some other point - just that they were far away from one another.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but this must be an error - "distanted" is not a word.

In its place you could use either:

- *Distant* - but this is relative - saying both cities are distant would mean they are far away from *you*, not necessarily from each other.
- *Remote* - this would mean the two cities are isolated, away from anything else, which would include *everything*, not just the other city.

There is also the word *distanced*, which means two things have been separated - that probably is not appropriate for two existing cities.

However, as your sentence goes on to say that the two cities are "far away from each other", there seems little need to repeat that point. You could simply say:

> The two cities are far away from each other.

Comment: The problem is I only want the first part of the sentence; question is updated.